# Point free style for two functions "combined" (not composed)

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, pointfree, fp-ts

I'm doing this in TypeScript, but would be OK with a response in another language with FP abilities.

Say I've got `const foo = (a:A) => M` and `const bar = (b:B) => N`. I'd like to run these functions "in parallel" (doesn't have to be actual parallel IO but they aren't dependent on each other) but by defining the "composition" in a point-free manner.

If they were actually composable (say `a` returns `B` instead of `M`), I could write

```
const composed = flow(foo, bar) // (a:A) => N
```

Instead, I'd like some way to combine them them (let's call this `magicCompose`) such that my point-free style yields

```
const newFn = magicCompose(foo, bar) // (a:A, b:B) => [M,N] or ({a:A, b:B}) => [M,N] or (p:[A,B]) => [M,N]
```

Is this a possibility?

Using `fp-ts` in TypeScript I have `sequenceT` that lets me treat these as Readers and combine them like so

```
const _ = sequenceT(reader)(foo, bar)
```

However, this is invalid if `foo` and `bar` take different params. I can use `local: (E => R) => (Reader<E, any>) => Reader<R, any>` but then I have to break point-free to write

```
const _ = sequenceT(reader)(
  local((params:{a:A,b:B}) => params.a)(foo),
  local((params:{a:A,b:B}) => params.b)(bar)) // Reader<{a:A,b:B}, [M,N]>
```

which is effectively `({a:A,b:B}) => [M,N]` but unfortunately it's not point-free. If I were to make optics like `_a = Lens.fromProp<{a:A,b:B}>()('a')` and `_b = Lens.fromProp<{a:A,b:B}>()('b')` and then have

```
const _ = sequenceT(reader)(
  local(_a.get)(foo),
  local(_b.get)(bar)) // Reader<{a:A,b:B}, [M,N]>
```

But that seems like cheating to get point-free.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with fp-ts but here is the first idea I have for this - you can turn `foo` and `bar` into thunks. A thunk is a function that takes no parameters - often it's made *from* a function that takes parameters, so you can just do `partial(foo, a)` to get one. You now have two functions that when executed produce a result. Maybe there that makes it easier to handle them as you don't need to manage the inputs.

Comment: Why are you so keen to write this point-free? (In Haskell it's called [`bimap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html#v:bimap), by the way.)

Comment: Just an excuse to practice PF since I'm new to it. I've been writing an API library where I have a `fn1 = (a:A) => B`, and it gets composed with other functions, and ultimately `export const apiCall = (a:A) => pipe(fn1(a), ...)` and I like being able to reduce the number of times I explicitly provide the params. With fp-ts I can do `export const apiCall = flow(fn1, ...)` and never provide the params. So I avoid duplication and it makes refactoring easier. That's what made me interested in PF and now I'm going hard at it.

Comment: Just in this case, it's not as straightforward. I have two functions that rely on *parts* of some initial parameters and I'd like to avoid `export const apiCall = (a:A, b:B) => combine(fnTakingA, fnTakingB)` if possible

Comment: For now I've settled on treating these as `Reader<{A,B}, C>` and I can use `Reader.local` to mutate the environment `{A,B}` passed to `fnA` and `fnB` and that has solved my problem. Just feels inelegant.

Comment: Do you care that `newFn` will be point-free, or do you want to implement the `magicCompose` itself in a point-free way?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Also the arrow generalisation [`***`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-42--42--42-) :-)